# 'which are in stark contrast to' or just 'in stark contrast to'?

Tags: grammaticality, colloquial-language

> Those clerics, who often have views on life ***which are in stark contrast to*** the Belgian lifestyle, have been ***provoking identity crises in many immigrant youths***, making them vulnerable for radicalization.

I was wondering if the sentence above is correct. I'm not so sure about the two parts in italic. Is it better to say "Those clerics, who often have views on life ***in stark contrast to*** the Belgian lifestyle..." 
and to provoke a crisis? would a native English speaker say that?

Comment: Don't accept my answer yet, or people who know more about this than I do may be unwilling to answer. @araucaria may be able to shed light on the omission of relative pronouns in this particular situation.

Answer (score 3):

> ...views on life **which are** in stark contrast to...

Which is a relative pronoun. Under some circumstances, it is permissible to omit the relative pronoun (and the be-verb), though the sentence is usually clearer if it is included.

> ...provoking identity crises...

Unlike a regular crisis, an [identity crisis](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/identity-crisis) is a psychological phenomenon: a ​feeling of being ​uncertain about who or what you are.

A cleric who proposes a lifestyle that is different to that in which you were brought up, might provoke an identity crisis.

Comment: You can replace *which* with *that*, but you can't omit it here.  A bare relative is not possible when the gap is in subject position.